# PHP Instagram API Get Photos of 2 Hashtags with Min Date

Tags: php, api, instagram

I could not find any help on this. I really appreciate if anyone knows! I would like to pool 2 photos from 2 hashtags with a specific min and max datetime. Is there any way to extract it from Instagram API?